# unset from array causing internal server error

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to merge two arrays by removing duplicate values.
that is  if  `$array_two[$i]->id == $array_one[$j]->yelp_id` then it is a duplicate.
so i am trying to remove it.

This is my code..

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array_two);$i++)
   {
   for($j=0;$j<count($array_one); $j++)
    {
      if($array_two[$i]->id == $array_one[$j]->yelp_id)
       {            

        //print_r($array_two[$i]);
        unset($array_two[$i]);

        }

    }
}
$array=array_merge($array_one,$array_two);
```

When i do this i am getting an

> internal server error 500..

but when i am printing using `print_r` i am getting the duplicate entry..

what is wrong in this code?

please help

Comment: did you read error.log?

Comment: Are you sure that the indexes are numeric?

Comment: array_merge automatically handle duplicate entry and over right the first array. no need to do unset(). please check http://php.net/array_merge

Comment: yes the indexes are numeric.i am getting result on print_r. also here structure of $array_one and $array_two are different. i am looking for duplicates by comparing "ïd" of first array and yelp_id of second array so array_merge wont remove the duplicates

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `break;` after `unset($array_two[$i]);` cause it is still going through the `for($j)` and trying to hit that value again but it doesn't exist anymore.

Also you should move the `count()` functions outside the for loop declaration. It is recalculating the length each time and if you remove items from the array it won't hit the last few items in the array as the count will decrease each time.

```
$count1 = count($array_two);
$count2 = count($array_one);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count1; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $count2; $j++) {
        if ($array_two[$i]->id == $array_one[$j]->yelp_id) {
            unset($array_two[$i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but you should change the `count()` functions also, if you have duplicates at the end `$array_two` they won't be found if you have duplicates in front of them.